# Обработка события на множестве динамических элементов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Друзья, кто умеет писать правильно и красиво, подскажите как лучше писать такие вещи и от чего нужно отталкиваться при выборе решения.
Допустим есть модальное окошко, там динамически формируется контент с кнопочками "btn1", "btn2", "btn3". Модальное окошко #modal, уже есть на странице и скрыто. Задача: прописать обработку клика на эти кнопочки.
Лично я вижу два вариант и не пойму, что выбрать и на что нужно смотреть чтобы принять решение.

Вариант 1:

```
        $('#modal').on('click', '.btn1', function(e) {
            // Some action
        });

        $('#modal').on('click', '.btn2', function(e) {
            // Some action
        });

        $('#modal').on('click', '.btn3', function(e) {
            // Some action
        });
```

Не нравится:
 - Дублирование конструкции

Вариант 2:

```
$('#modal').on('click','.some-common-btn-class' ,function(e){
            var typeBtn = $(e.target).attr('some-unique-property');
            switch (typeBtn) {
                case 'type1':
                    // some action
                    break;
                case 'type2':
                    // some action
                    break;
                case 'type3':
                    // some action
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Не нравится:
 - Необходимость в дополнительном классе .some-common-btn-class
 - Логика принятия решения внутри обработчика

Вообщем у кого какие варианты, делитесь :)

Comment: А вот так не подойдет ?

    $('#modal').on('click', '.btn1', action1);
    $('#modal').on('click', '.btn2', action2);
    $('#modal').on('click', '.btn3', action3);
    
    function action1(e) {
    
    }
    
    function action2(e) {
    
    }
    
    function action3(e) {
    
    }

если у вас actionы разные, то никак не получится не описывать их :)
ещё момент, btn1,btn2,btn3 точно повторяются ? в смысле нельзя сделать их id ? это решило бы проблему в случае case.

Comment: Можно и id. C вынесенными обработчиками выглядит чуть красивее, согласен.

Comment: с ID и case я бы лично не стал бы заморачиваться, т.к. описание этого будет ещё длиннее. лучше просто сделайте как я показал. это читается легко, и обработчики можно куда-нить задвинуть, чтобы не портили вид.

Answer (score 2):

В javascript далеко не спец. Недавно начал знакомство. Поэтому решение может быть "корявым".
Хотелось бы услышать мнение других пользователей.

Раз класс блоков div, на которые нужно вешать событие отличается только цифрой, то:

```
/** 
 * Создаем массив функций для каждого div.
 * Тут я предположил, что нужны уникальные функции для каждого блока
 */

var func_list = [    
    function (el) {
        alert($(el).text() + ' 1');
    },
    function (el) {
        alert($(el).text() + ' 2');
    },
    function (el) {
        alert($(el).text() + ' 3');
    },
    function (el) {
        var n = $('div[class^=btn]').length + 1,
            btn = '<div class="btn' + n +'">new ' + n + '</div>';
        $('#modal').append(btn);
    },
    function (el) {
        alert('Hi there');
    }
];

/* Навешиваем функцию соответствующему ей блоку (по порядку) */

func_list.forEach(function (func, i) {
    var selector = 'div:nth-of-type(' + (i + 1) + ')';
    $('#modal').on('click', selector, function () {
        func(this);
    });
});
});
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/58d73/5/)**

Comment: @VenZell там же динамически добавляются эти кнопки, поэтому и стоит `$('#modal').on()` вот зацени с одним хэндлером http://jsfiddle.net/58d73/2/

Comment: @eicto, исправил пример под динамическое добавление. Так лучше?  
Хотя, наверное, нет из-за двойного (по факту) цикла. Просто не хотелось повторяться.

Comment: сойдет                     

.

Comment: Я тоже не спец, но мне кажется завязывать алгоритм навешивания обработчиков на конкретной логике именования элементов совсем не круто.

Comment: @Ridzhi, отвязал от именования.

Comment: Вы меня немного не поняли, ваша реализация завязана на том что кнопки будут иметь класс btn(i). А мне интересна реализация, конструкции которая будет работать с любыми селекторами и сведет дублирование к минимуму. У меня появилась на этот счет идея, чуть позже выложу.

Answer (score 0):

Свежий вариант, завязан на расширении jquery.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    onEventMap: function(eventMap) {
        for(var event in eventMap) {
            var handlers =  eventMap[event];
            for(var elem in handlers) {
                $(this).on(event, elem, handlers[elem]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Теперь можно писать так:

```
$('#modal').onEventMap({
    click: {
       '.btn1' : function(e) {
           // some actions
       },
       '.btn2' : function(e) {
           // some actions
       },
       '.btn3' : function(e) {
           // some actions
       },
    },
    mouseover: {
        '.somediv': function(e){
            // some action
        }
    }
});
```

Критика приветствуется.

Answer (score -2):

Чтобы не дублировать селекторы:

```
var modal = $('#modal');
```

Если одно, то так:

```
modal.find('.btn1, .btn2, .btn3').on('click', function(){
    alert(123);
});
```

Если разные, то так:

```
modal.find('.btn1').on('click', function() {
  alert(1);
});
modal.find('.btn2').on('click', function() {
  alert(2);
});
modal.find('.btn3').on('click', function() {
  alert(3);
});
```

Альтернативный вариант:

```
function bindAction(handler, type){
  modal.find(handler).on('click', function() {
    switch (type){
      case 1:
        alert(1);
        break;
      case 2:
        alert(2);
        break;
      case 3: 
        alert(3);
        break;
    }
  });
};

//вызов
bindAction('.btn1', 1);                     
bindAction('.btn2', 2); 
bindAction('.btn3', 3);
```

[Демо](http://codepen.io/FlamesoFF/pen/osbLp)